# Sinônimo de tag Pug & Jade

Tags: bug, tags, tags-sinônimas

A linguagem Jade foi renomeada para Pug.

O motivo da mudança está descrito na página do projeto no GitHub. https://github.com/pugjs/pug#rename-from-jade

Comment: Alguém pode confirmar se todas as perguntas já postadas são sobre a mesma coisa nas duas *tags*?

Comment: Seria o caso de ver se alguma ocorrência da tag Jade se refere ao que foi chamado de Pug agora. Não é o caso de renomear e nem criar sinônimo, e sim de remover a Jade onde não serve, e aplicar a tag Pug, já que não tem definição nenhuma na tag Jade. Se não chama mais jade, não é sinônimo. (mas o aviso é útil, a pergunta é pertinente)

Comment: Já tinha [respondido sobre isso aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127261/129). Na altura achei que o Jade ainda era mais conhecido, mas agora é altura de mudar mesmo. Vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Acho que pode ser caso de deixar mais algum tempo. Há algumas mudanças de API e pode ser útil distinguir Jade e Pug para os casos de API antiga.

Comment: @Sergio se Jade virar sinonimo já não resolve? A não ser que exista outro Jade

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim sinónimo é uma variante. Podemos ter sinónimo e depois mesclar ou deixar assim para sempre, uma vez que "Jade" deve ir desaparecendo.

Comment: @bigown, fiz uma busca por perguntas com a tag Jade e todas são sobre o template-engine/linguagem renomeado para Pug.